# Unity WheelCollider Moving in Wrong Direction When Centering

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, wheelcollider

When I try to adjust the center of the WheelCollider along the Y-axis it doesn't go straight up along the axis.  Rather, it goes up and to the right.
If anyone knows why this is happening I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

[Wheel Collider Center x=0, y=0, z=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj9QT.png)

[Wheel Collider Center x=0, y=0.1, z=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CGzs.png)

Comment: Is it possible that the WheelCollider is a child of a parent object with that orientation?

Comment: @IanMcCleary That's what I thought, but I checked the parent objects and both of them have the y-axis pointed up.  The front two WheelColliders work fine.  It's the rear two that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  It was the rotation and scale of the actual Wheel Colliders.  The rotations weren't set to 0 and the scales on the two rear wheels were negative.

I zeroed out the rotations and removed the negative signs, and voila, it worked!